# Operate LG G2 phone from Desktop

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen, remote-access, lg-g2

My LG G2's screen just got a chip in it, and consequently only the top 1/4 of the screen will register touch.

The phone is **not** rooted, but I have developer options and USB debugging activated. Is there any way I can mirror the phone on a PC or Mac? (I prefer Mac, but have access to Windows 8 as well.) I'm talking about full control with keyboard and mouse.

I just want to know if I can hobble through until the new Nexus comes out and I can finally be rid of this old phone.

Comment: This seems really promising, but I'm having trouble. When I open Vysor, and click "Find Devices", it shows my phone but nothing happens when I select it.

Comment: I'll create an answer and move the discussion there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Vysor first. As long as USB debugging is on you shouldn't even need to do anything on the phone to get it running. Mouse simulates touch while keyboard input is passed through. If you don't type in English then input method support might be a bit clumsy.

Comment: Vysor uses its own ADB daemon by default which is not a good thing. Do you have Android SDK or any other sort of ADB access installed? If yes, close Vysor, manually start ADB daemon by executing any ADB command (e.g. `adb devices`) from command prompt. Try again after that.

Comment: If not, get this set of ADB ([link](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24521665358595410)). You also need LG drivers if you haven't, of course.

Comment: I have installed the Android SDK on my Mac (haven't tried yet on Windows) but I don't think I ever installed any drivers. Do you know where I can find the drivers for my phone? Are these universal or Windows exclusive?

Comment: @Patch "LG United Mobile Driver" ([link](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24421527759887436)). I believe it's Windows only.

Comment: @Patch Or "LG VZW United Driver" if yours is a Verizon variant. I have them hosted on my own AndroidFileHost too: [link](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?a=show&w=files&flid=54980)

Comment: I do have a Verizon phone. I am now on my Windows machine, and still no luck. I installed the ADB .exe you linked above, and ran the command, but Vysor now says No Devices Found.

Comment: I also installed the Driver you linked, but cannot find an installer for the Verzion version. When I Google it, everything is just talking about uninstalling it. On top of that, when I run the ADB command in Command Prompt, it doesn't list my phone.

Comment: @Patch My comment was edited to include a link for the Verizon driver. You'll need the phone to be detected by ADB for Vysor to work. Just for confirmation, do you have USB debugging on?

Comment: Thank you so much! That driver did the trick. I installed it, re-ran the command, and re-opened Vysor, and it worked.

Comment: @Patch Awesome. Hope you enjoy your new Nexus should you decide to get one. If you can accept its polarizing design, that is :)